# trying to take the address of an enum type

Tags: c++, enums

in effective C++, I learn that item 2 says it's not legal to take the address of an enum anywhere in the program and it's typically not legal to take the address of a #define, either.
but i write such code that it tries to take the address of an enum type:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
enum week { mon=1, tue }day;
week* a = &day;
return 0;
}
```

it can run without mistakes. so i feel confused about this item.

Comment: `day` is a local variable, not an enum.  `week` is an enum.

Comment: They probably meant you can't take the address of one of the values of an enum, so `& mon` or `&tue` wouldn't compile. But `day` is basically a variable of some integer type, so taking its address is like taking the address of another integer variable. You can't take the address of the enum type either, but then, you can't take the address of any type (e.g., `& int` won't compile, and makes no real sense).

Comment: You have to differ between enumeration *types* (like `week`), enumeration *constants* (lkike `mon`) and *variables* of an enumeration type.

Comment: While it turned out harmless in this case, do note that "it can run without mistakes" is a very poor indicator in C++ of undefined behavior, especially when poking around with aliasing and reference semantics. There is a *ton* of undefined behavior in C++ that will "just work" sometimes in some compilers on some computers and then fail at the wrong moment, or crash when an optimizer hits it.

Comment: *"Undefined behavior means anything can happen inlcuding but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program that has UB. The program may just crash."*

Comment: If you read something that does not make sense to you, it is often wise to provide an exact quote of what you read. Paraphrasing what you read colors it with your own misunderstanding, which could make your question hopelessly confused.

Comment: Reopened. There is no undefined behavior here.

Comment: Types don't have addresses. Variables/objects do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code introduces five identifiers, namely `week`, `mon`, `tue`, `day`, and `a`. Each of the first four could reasonably be called "an enum" in a paraphrase of a misunderstood quote. Without a quote, it is difficult to tell to which of these the book refers. However, it is possible to list which identifiers can and cannot have their address taken.

- `&week` -- **not** legal to take the address of a type
- `&mon` -- **not** legal to take the address of an enumerator
- `&tue` -- **not** legal to take the address of an enumerator
- `&day` -- **legal** to take the address of a variable

The upshot of the quote is probably that enumerators – the values of an enumeration type, e.g. `mon`, `tue` – are not variables, so their address cannot be taken. Syntactically, the valid uses of `mon` closely match the valid uses of the numeric literal `1`. In particular, just like one cannot take the address of a numeric literal (no `&1` allowed), one cannot take the address of an enumerator (no `&mon` allowed).

Comment: "*the enumerates*" The correct term for these, from the standard, is "enumerators". The "enumeration" is the type that gets defined, and the "enumerators" are the things that go inside the enumeration definition.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks. Apparently I picked up the wrong terminology years ago and never noticed. It's even the wrong part of speech (verb instead of noun). Oops.

Answer (score 0):

In that phrase - 'the address of an enum', an 'enum' means a symbol you defined as a constant. In your code, `mon` and `tue` are enums. Experiment yourself like this.

```
void *p = &mon;
```

Comment: *"a symbol you defined as a constant"* -- this might not be how you want to describe the situation. It is possible to take the address of some symbols defined as constants. For example, given the definition `constexpr int monday = 1;` it is legal to take the address of this constant, as in `&monday`. So while your conclusion is good, your supporting argument is weak.

Comment: @JaMiT, I just said the correct interpretation of English words, not the appropriateness of a syntax of C++. The original sentence in the book is "For example, it’s legal to
take the address of a const, but it’s not legal to take the address of an
enum, and it’s typically not legal to take the address of a #define,
either.".